# PyQt5. textBrowser.append не работает при вызове во второстепенном потоке

Tags: python, pyqt5, многопоточность, qthread, qtextbrowser

Как вызвать `textBrowser.append` в другом потоке?

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore
from mydesign import Ui_MainWindow
import sys
from time import sleep
from threading import Thread
import datetime
from PyQt5.QtCore import QRunnable, QThreadPool


class Runnable(QRunnable):
    def __init__(self, this):
        super().__init__()
        self.this = this

    def run(self):
        while not self.this.isClosed:
            sleep(1)
            ctime = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
            self.this.ui.textBrowser.append(ctime)  # <-- Error!


class mywindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(mywindow, self).__init__()
        self.this = self
        self.isClosed = False
        self.setWindowOpacity(0.95)
        self.bt_count = 0
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.ui.pushButton.clicked.connect(
            self.button_evt
        )
        self.runTasks()  # <-- Error!

    def button_evt(self):
        self.ui.textBrowser.setText(
            "Вы нажали на кнопку %d раз(а)" % self.bt_count)
        self.bt_count += 1

    def keyPressEvent(self, e):
        if e.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_End:
            self.close()
        exit()

    def thread(self):
        self.t1 = Thread(target=self.Operation, daemon=True)
        self.t1.start()

    def runTasks(self):
        pool = QThreadPool.globalInstance()
        runnable = Runnable(self)
        pool.start(runnable)

    def event(self, event):

        if event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.Close:
            print(f"Oкно закрытo (QCloseEvent).")
            self.isClosed = True
        return QtWidgets.QWidget.event(self, event)


app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
application = mywindow()
application.show()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Вывод:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вываливаются непредсказуемые ошибки.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Почитайте:

[realpython.com/python-pyqt-qthread](https://realpython.com/python-pyqt-qthread/)

[stackoverflow.com/questions/6783194/background-thread-with-qthread-in-pyqt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6783194/background-thread-with-qthread-in-pyqt)

Comment: Спасибо, разберусь!

Comment: @LINUX_ADMIN пожалуйста, когда разберетесь не забудьте поделиться решением, которое отвечает на ваш вопрос.

Answer (score 3):

1. **`НЕЛЬЗЯ взаимодействовать с виджетами в дополнительном потоке`**.
   Сигналы и слоты используются для связи между объектами.
   Механизм сигналов и слотов - центральная особенность Qt и, вероятно,
   часть, которая больше всего отличается от функций, предоставляемых другими фреймворками.
   Больше https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html
2. Нет необходимости использовать дополнительные библиотеки
   (`time`, `threading`, `datetime`).

Вот вам одно из возможных решений:

```
import sys
#from time import sleep
#from threading import Thread
#import datetime

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.Qt import *
# ? from mydesign import Ui_MainWindow

        
class WorkThread(QThread):
    threadSignal = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def run(self, *args, **kwargs):
        while True:
            self.msleep(1000)
#            ctime = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
            ctime = QDateTime.currentDateTime().toString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss")
            self.threadSignal.emit(ctime)


class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        
        self.bt_count = 0
        self.setWindowOpacity(0.95)
        
        self.centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(self.centralWidget)
        
        self.textBrowser = QTextBrowser()
        self.pushButton = QPushButton('Button')
        self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.button_evt)        
 
        self.layout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.centralWidget)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.textBrowser)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.pushButton)

        self.runTasks()  
        
    def button_evt(self):
        self.bt_count += 1
        self.textBrowser.setText(
            "Вы нажали на кнопку %d раз(а)" % self.bt_count)

    def keyPressEvent(self, e):
        if e.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_End:
            self.close()
#        exit()

    def runTasks(self):
        self.thread = WorkThread()
        self.thread.threadSignal.connect(self.on_threadSignal)
        self.thread.start()
        
    def on_threadSignal(self, ctime):
        self.textBrowser.append(ctime)
        
        
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    application = MyWindow()
    application.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]